# How to get the index of a key in a hash?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get the index of a key in a hash.

I know how to do this in an array:

```
arr = ['Done', 13, 0.4, true]

a = arr.index('Done')

puts a
```

Is there a method or some sort of way to do this something like this with a key in a hash? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an example containing a hash and the expected result?

Comment: BTW, what's your use case? Why are you interested in the key's _index_? I cannot think of any practical use for it :-)

Comment: @Stephan I'm writing an open-source pentesting tool, and need to arranged data in an orderly fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashes aren't usually treated as ordered structures, they simply have a list of keys and values corresponding to those keys.

It's true that in Ruby hashes are technically ordered, but there's very rarely an actual use case for treating them as such.

If what you want to do is find the *key* corresponding to a *value* in a hash, you can simply use the [Hash#key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-key) method:

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
hash.key(1) # => :a
```

I suppose you could use `hash.keys.index(hash.key(1))` to get `0` since it's the first value, but again, I wouldn't advise doing this because it's not typical use of the data structure

Answer (score 4):

There are at least a couple ways you can get this information, the 2 that come to mind are Enumerable's [`find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index) method to pass each element to a block and check for your key:

```
hash.find_index { |key, _| key == 'Done' }
```

or you could get all the [`keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-keys) from your hash as an array and then look up the index as you've been doing:

```
hash.keys.index('Done')
```